# Combining 2 queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, parameters

I am trying to export employee time card information.  The export works fine, but i'm trying to factor in the tip for employees.  The Tip an employee receives is based on the amount of hours worked, divided by the total number of hours in a specific set of departments times the tip amount.  For example:

Location 1 has 5 employees.  2 Groups

Manager - Not Eligible for Tip 
Employee - Eligible for Tip

I need to get the total hours for the "Employee" Group, and the total hours for the employees in the Employee group.

Lets say the employee Group had 111 hours this week.  and the hours of the employees were:

```
Jim: 22
Bob: 32
Pete: 29
Dave: 28
```

The Tip for this week was $100.00

To find each members tip, I would do:

```
Jim's Tip: 22/111 * 100 = $19.82
Bob's Tip: 32/111 * 100 = $28.83
Pete's Tip: 29/111 * 100 = $26.13
Dave's Tip: 28/111 * 100 = $25.23
```

The last part is the Manager, Tim, was NOT eligible for tips, but needs to be included in my export.

I can get the query's to run separately for:

```
1) to run for just the groups eligible for tips and calculate the tip
2) to run for all employees leaving tip out.
```

Here is the output I get:

```
Name   Location   OtherNumber   RegHours   OT Hours   TIP
Jim's    1           12345         22          0    $19.82
Bob's    1           12395         32          0    $28.83
Pete's   1           31654         29          0    $26.13
Dave's   1           03948         28          0    $25.23
```

Here is the output I should get:

```
Name   Location   OtherNumber   RegHours   OT Hours   TIP
Tim      1           30984         40          0    $0
Jim's    1           12345         22          0    $19.82
Bob's    1           12395         32          0    $28.83
Pete's   1           31654         29          0    $26.13
Dave's   1           03948         28          0    $25.23
```

Here is my code:

Code to get "ALL" Employees regardless of group

```
SELECT        ftc.sFirstName + ' ' + ftc.sLastName AS sName, Account.sLocationDesc, Employees.sOtherNumber, SUM(ftc.RegHours) AS RegHours, SUM(ftc.OTHours) 
                         AS OTHours
FROM            dbo.fTimeCard(@StartDate, @EndDate, @DeptList, @iActive, @EmployeeList) AS ftc LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         Employees ON ftc.lEmployeeID = Employees.lEmployeeID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         Account ON
                             (SELECT        CASE WHEN Employees.lLocationID IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE Employees.lLocationID END AS Expr1
                               FROM            Employees
                               WHERE        (lEmployeeID = ftc.lEmployeeID)) = Account.lLocationID
WHERE        (ftc.RegHours > 0) AND (ftc.RegHours IS NOT NULL)
GROUP BY Account.sLocationDesc, Employees.sOtherNumber, ftc.lEmployeeID, ftc.sLastName, ftc.sFirstName
```

Here is my code to find out the Tip, and how much each employee should get from the eligible group:

```
SELECT        t3.sName, t3.TotalHours, t3.TotalHours / t4.TotalDepartmentHours * @TIP AS Tip
FROM            (SELECT        ftc.sFirstName + ' ' + ftc.sLastName AS sName, SUM(ftc.RegHours) + SUM(ftc.OTHours) AS TotalHours, ftc.lEmployeeID
                          FROM            dbo.fTimeCard(@StartDate, @EndDate, @DeptListTip, @iActive, @EmployeeList) AS ftc LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                                    Employees ON ftc.lEmployeeID = Employees.lEmployeeID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                                    Account ON
                                                        (SELECT        CASE WHEN Employees.lLocationID IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE Employees.lLocationID END AS Expr1
                                                          FROM            Employees
                                                          WHERE        (lEmployeeID = ftc.lEmployeeID)) = Account.lLocationID
                          WHERE        (ftc.RegHours > 0) AND (ftc.RegHours IS NOT NULL)
                          GROUP BY ftc.lEmployeeID, ftc.sLastName, ftc.sFirstName) AS t3 CROSS JOIN
                             (SELECT        SUM(ftc.RegHours) + SUM(ftc.OTHours) AS TotalDepartmentHours
                               FROM            dbo.fTimeCard(@StartDate, @EndDate, @DeptListTip, @iActive, @EmployeeList) AS ftc LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                                         Employees AS Employees_1 ON ftc.lEmployeeID = Employees_1.lEmployeeID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                                         Account AS Account_1 ON
                                                             (SELECT        CASE WHEN Employees.lLocationID IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE Employees.lLocationID END AS Expr1
                                                               FROM            Employees
                                                               WHERE        (lEmployeeID = ftc.lEmployeeID)) = Account_1.lLocationID
                               WHERE        (ftc.RegHours > 0) AND (ftc.RegHours IS NOT NULL)) AS t4
```

Here is my query Combining both where the output does not include the "Tim" the manager"

```
SELECT        t1.sName, t1.sLocationDesc, t1.sOtherNumber, t1.RegHours, t1.OTHours, t2.Tip
FROM            (SELECT        ftc.sFirstName + ' ' + ftc.sLastName AS sName, Account.sLocationDesc, Employees.sOtherNumber, SUM(ftc.RegHours) AS RegHours, SUM(ftc.OTHours) 
                                                    AS OTHours, ftc.lEmployeeID
                          FROM            dbo.fTimeCard(@StartDate, @EndDate, @DeptList, @iActive, @EmployeeList) AS ftc LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                                    Employees ON ftc.lEmployeeID = Employees.lEmployeeID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                                    Account ON
                                                        (SELECT        CASE WHEN Employees.lLocationID IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE Employees.lLocationID END AS Expr1
                                                          FROM            Employees
                                                          WHERE        (lEmployeeID = ftc.lEmployeeID)) = Account.lLocationID
                          WHERE        (ftc.RegHours > 0) AND (ftc.RegHours IS NOT NULL)
                          GROUP BY Account.sLocationDesc, Employees.sOtherNumber, ftc.lEmployeeID, ftc.sLastName, ftc.sFirstName) AS t1 INNER JOIN
                             (SELECT        t3.sName, t3.TotalHours, t3.TotalHours / t4.TotalDepartmentHours * @TIP AS Tip, t3.lEmployeeID
                               FROM            (SELECT        ftc.sFirstName + ' ' + ftc.sLastName AS sName, SUM(ftc.RegHours) + SUM(ftc.OTHours) AS TotalHours, ftc.lEmployeeID
                                                         FROM            dbo.fTimeCard(@StartDate, @EndDate, @DeptListTip, @iActive, @EmployeeList) AS ftc LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                                                                   Employees AS Employees_2 ON ftc.lEmployeeID = Employees_2.lEmployeeID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                                                                   Account AS Account_2 ON
                                                                                       (SELECT        CASE WHEN Employees.lLocationID IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE Employees.lLocationID END AS Expr1
                                                                                         FROM            Employees
                                                                                         WHERE        (lEmployeeID = ftc.lEmployeeID)) = Account_2.lLocationID
                                                         WHERE        (ftc.RegHours > 0) AND (ftc.RegHours IS NOT NULL)
                                                         GROUP BY ftc.lEmployeeID, ftc.sLastName, ftc.sFirstName) AS t3 CROSS JOIN
                                                             (SELECT        SUM(ftc.RegHours) + SUM(ftc.OTHours) AS TotalDepartmentHours
                                                               FROM            dbo.fTimeCard(@StartDate, @EndDate, @DeptListTip, @iActive, @EmployeeList) AS ftc LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                                                                         Employees AS Employees_1 ON ftc.lEmployeeID = Employees_1.lEmployeeID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                                                                         Account AS Account_1 ON
                                                                                             (SELECT        CASE WHEN Employees.lLocationID IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE Employees.lLocationID END AS Expr1
                                                                                               FROM            Employees
                                                                                               WHERE        (lEmployeeID = ftc.lEmployeeID)) = Account_1.lLocationID
                                                               WHERE        (ftc.RegHours > 0) AND (ftc.RegHours IS NOT NULL)) AS t4) AS t2 ON t1.lEmployeeID = t2.lEmployeeID
```

You'll notice it's basically the same query, except I used a different parameter for the group... I use `@DeptList` in one and set that to "All", and use `@DeptListTip` and set that to the specific Group, in this case "Employee"

Comment: Is @DeptListTip a string or a table-valued parameter?

Comment: Table-Valued Parameter

Answer (score 1):

Since you have issues only with managers data All you have to do is add a union.

ie. your final code

```
UNION
SELECT 'Tim','1','30984','40','0','$0'
```

Comment: This will change based on location.  For example, at other locations we will have 3 groups not be eligble for tips.  Could be as many as 15 employees.

Comment: That's what the first query is (t1).  You'll see broke it into 2 seperate queries, but only want the "Tip" column from the tip query.  I want tit to link using lEmployeeID

Comment: hmmm.  Or I could Break the 2 out.  and use the union.  How would I union the 2 queries above?  never Used union

Comment: Try using a With clause so that you can retrict it to a temp table and then filter it out

Comment: Actually I don't like the union.  It would be to difficult to break out the remaining groups... I already have to break out specific groups, per location as the program loops through.  Would prefer to mash the 2 queries together, and only use the "Tip" from the second query

Answer (score 0):

You may save your result in a temporary table, so that you don't have to call your Table Valued Function again and again. Also it is NOT clear how you are recognizing an Employee that he/she is NOT eligible for, so that part I guess is missing from my solution. I can update it if you provide me details.

Anyway this is a very simplified form of your work. **Notice that how I am doing joining to master tables, so that I don't have to do a `Group By` on `Description` fields.**

*This may NOT give you the desired results, but hopefully it will point you in the right direction.*

**UPDATE:**
I have included the Tip Eligibility checking, however your function should return the `@DepList` as a Table Field, so that we can filter on query level, which will save the function calling for 2 times.

```
DECLARE @tblfTimeCard table(lEmployeeID int, TotalRegHours int, TotalOTHours int, HasTip bit)

-- first we will get all the data and do the basic summing here
-- you are also picking sFirstName and sLastName from Table Valued function
-- while I think same fields can be extracted from Employee master
-- therefore, we should only return the lEmployeeID from TVF
INSERT INTO @tblfTimeCard(lEmployeeID, TotalRegHours, TotalOTHours, HasTip)
    SELECT    lEmployeeiD, SUM(ftc.RegHours) AS TotalRegHours, SUM(ftc.OTHours) AS TotalOTHours, 0 AS HasTip
    FROM    dbo.fTimeCard(@StartDate, @EndDate, @DeptList, @iActive, @EmployeeList) AS ftc 
    WHERE      (ftc.RegHours > 0) AND (ftc.RegHours IS NOT NULL)
    GROUP BY lEmployeeID

-- set HasTip flag for the Employees who are eligible for Tip
UPDATE 
    SET HasTip = 1
FROM    @tblfTimeCard AS F
WHERE    
    Exists(
        SELECT    1
        FROM    dbo.fTimeCard(@StartDate, @EndDate, @DeptListTip, @iActive, @EmployeeList) AS ftc 
        WHERE      ftc.lEmployeeID = F.lEmployeeID
                (ftc.RegHours > 0) AND (ftc.RegHours IS NOT NULL)
    )

SELECT    EDT.lEmployeeID, EDT.TotalRegHours, EDT.TotalOTHours,
        CASE WHEN EDT.HasTip = 1 THEN 
            (EDT.TotalRegHours + EDT.TotalOTHours) / EDT.TotalDepartmentHours * @TIP 
        ELSE
            0
        END AS Tip,
        E.sFirstName + ' ' + E.sLastName AS sName,
        A.sLocationDesc
FROM    (
        SELECT    lEmployeeID, f.TotalRegHours, f.TotalOTHours,
                (
                SELECT     SUM(TotalRegHours, TotalOTHours)
                FROM    @tblfTimeCard
                -- TO DO: here the SUM is happening on whole @tblfTimeCard, while you may
                -- want to group for the particular Group, so you may need to put a filter 
                -- something like
                -- WHERE GroupID = f.GroupID
                ) AS TotalDepartmentHours,
                f.HasTip
        FROM    @tblfTimeCard AS f
        ) AS EDT     -- Employee with Department Totals
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Employees AS E ON EDT.lEmployeeID = EDT.lEmployeeID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Accounts AS A ON ISNULL(E.lLocationID, 1) = A.lLocationID
```

Comment: who is and who is not eligible for the tip is based on the '@DeptList'.  I need the payroll export to include "ALL" employees (as they all need to be paid).  I need to calculate the tip by assigning the ID's to the '@DeptList'.  In this example "1" is the employee group.  "ALL" would include Employee and manager.  Does that make sense?

Comment: @Shmewnix, You are calling the same function with `@DepList` and `@DepListTip`. I suppose `@DepListTip` would only return Employees eligible for Tip, while `@DepList` would return all the Employees?

Comment: You are correct.  Ultimately I want to show the main query (ALL USERS) and then add the column for "Tip" for those users who are eligible for tip.  I assume "the EmployeeList" will probably need to change to "EmployeeListTip" as well.

Comment: I need to export the hours for ALL employees, so I can calculate the correct Regular hours, and OT hours.  Some employees will punch into multiple groups throughout the day.  Adding multiple time segments.  This is why all hours must be exported first, THEN I loop back around to calculate the tip.  The idea is to export all of this to a csv inside Vb.net  If I handle all of this on the Query side, it's less to worry about in VB.